# why to use local json data with useeffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i am getting this error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '({ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; } | ... 9 more ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<WineData[]>'.
> Type '({ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; } | ... 9 more ...' is not assignable to type 'WineData[]'.
> Type '{ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; } | ... 9 more ....' is not assignable to type 'WineData'.
> Type '{ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'WineData': alcohol, color_intensity, magnesium, wine_type
>
> ```
>     16 |
>     17 |   useEffect(() => {
>   > 18 |     setData(wineData);
>        |             ^^^^^^^^
>     19 |   }, []);
>     20 |
>     21 |   return (
> ```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is a big error, and one you will probably see often but it is actually quite simple once you understand it. Lets break it down.

This part is telling you that your object (winData) does not meet the type specification you have set for your useState.

```
TS2345: Argument of type '({ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; } | ... 9 more ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<WineData[]>'.
```

This part is telling you what fields and value types your wineData object has.

```
Type '({ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; } | ... 9 more ...' is not assignable to type 'WineData[]'. Type '{ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; } | ... 9 more ....' is not assignable to type 'WineData'. Type '{ Alcohol: number; "Malic Acid": number; Ash: number; "Alcalinity of ash": number; Magnesium: number; "Total phenols": number; Flavanoids: number; "Nonflavanoid phenols": number; Proanthocyanins: string; "Color intensity": number; Hue: number; "OD280/OD315 of diluted wines": number; Unknown: number; }'
```

Here is the important part. You have set your state to be of type wine_type.
winData, the object you are passing in to set state is missing the fields
alcohol, color_intensity and magnesium.

```
is missing the following properties from type 'WineData': alcohol, color_intensity, magnesium, wine_type
```

So to break it down here is an example of what is happening.

```
type Example = {
  param1: string;
  param2: string;
}
function ReactFunction() {
  const [params, setParams] = useState<Example | null>(null)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setParams({ param1: "param" }) // ERROR!: param2 not set 
  }
}
```

So how do you fix it?

2 options.

1. Ensure your object has the correct types before calling your setter.
2. Mark the fields as optional in your type definition.